# 404 Not Found 1 when view product detail page after customer logging

Tags: store-view, 404-page

I am trying to view product detail page after customer logging but it giving **404 Not Found 1** . But if I logged out the customer and then try to view product detail page , everything works fine.

I have tried everything of clearing cache , changing system->configuration->Genral->web setting.

I have Noticed that instead of getting "**view**" Action. It is getting "**noRoute**" Action

Comment: Did you intstall any extensions that are active on the product page routing or layout? Try disabling all third party extensions and see if it still happens.

Comment: Yes , I installed many extensions but don't know which one is creating problem. One more thing which I have noticed is that when I open the website and logged in customer first, then also everything works fine.

But if I logged out and Logged in again then there after I'll not able to see product detail page

Comment: As you said I tried disabling all the try party extensions but still getting same error. Is there any setting which not allow logged In user to view product detail ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally , I resolved it myself. But I do not got the reason for the same.

What I did is Reference from [Product pages displaying 404 page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4930/product-pages-displaying-404-page?rq=1)

I opened **Mage_Reports_Model_Event_Observer** and added a
**return true;**
In the begening of this observer method:
public function **catalogProductView**(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)

And it worked !!

But Then I clean the **report_viewed_product_index** and it is working fine even without returning true;

If anyone can explain reason for it. Most Welcome

Answer (score -1):

You have installed some extension who is behind this 404 error.
Double check the code and uninstall the used extension.
Try adding the following lines in .htaccess, it will ease your debugging by showing the errors

```
php_flag display_errors on
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE true
```

Comment: I have added these 2 lines in .htaccess file. Can you give me any idea how can I debug ? As I am new in magento. I have checked all extensions and still checking.

Comment: Are you using netbeans IDE?

Comment: No , I have Codelobster PHP edition and  JetBrains PHPStrom 8.0.3.

Should I use NetBeans ?

Comment: Actually netbeans support searching in whole project.
So that if you type 'noRoute' and search it in your whole project, it will show you the location where it is used, then you can find the reason from where and how it is comming.

Comment: I'll try to work with it. But same is possible with Codelobster PHP edition.
As when I debug into it. I saw that for ProductController , viewAction is calling when customer is logged out. But Don't know from where it is getting noRoute Action when customer logged in.

Comment: I think you should download net bean and then press 
ctrl+shift+f and type 
noroute
and it will show all files containing it.!
Good Luck..